# Unresolved import in VS Code Workspace

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import, importerror

I'm trying to set up my python programming environment for my CS class, and I am getting unresolved imports.

I have a workspace named "VSpace" set up, with two folders in it, "q1helper" and "courselib"

**In VS Code**

```
VSpace

q1helper

   |--q1solution.py

courselib

   |--goody.py

   |--driver.py

   |--dice.py

   |---...other random modules
```

When I try to import "goody" in q1solution.py, VS Code is unable to find it.

[Screenshot of Setup in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJaCy.png)

Comment: VSCode has its own tag.

Answer (score -1):

Add `__init__.py` in courselib folder, Is not necesary to put some in file, it could be empty

Comment: This did not work. There was still a ModuleNotFoundError